# MySQL - Select only if all in group are NULL

Tags: mysql

**My table is like this**:

```
ID|EID|priority|completed_forms|all_forms_in
1 |78 |NULL    |y              |y
2 |24 |NULL    |y              |y
3 |78 |1       |y              |y
```

**What I want to accomplish:**
select only the rows IF they all share the same `EID` and all share a priority of NULL and are marked 'y' for completed_forms and all_forms_in.

**What I've tried:** Here is my current select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
WHERE priority IS NULL AND EID in 
(
SELECT * FROM 
    (select EID from tasks 
    WHERE completed_form = 'y' AND all_forms_in = 'y' ) as priority_check
GROUP BY EID having count(*) = 2
)
```

**Expected result:** 
I want this to return NO rows because the select should ensure a return only if both rows are NULL.  In this case, ID 1 and ID 3 do not both share NULL.  Instead it is returning ID 1.

Comment: why shouldn't row with ID=2 be returned? does an EID have to have 2 rows or more with `priority = NULL`?

Comment: In this example it has to be exactly 2 (GROUP BY EID having count(*) = 2).  Since there is only 1 count of EID = 24, it should not be returned.  The only two rows it should look at are 1 and 3.  But it should not select anything unless they BOTH have NULL for priority.

Comment: can you provide SqlFiddle?

Comment: I've never used that before.  Not sure I did this correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9495

Comment: Try something like the following: [rextester.com/NDPGM89152](http://rextester.com/NDPGM89152).

Comment: @wchiquito In that case, it should return rows 1 and 3.  They are both null.  In that example it only returns the first ID.

Comment: See updated query in [rextester.com/NDPGM89152](http://rextester.com/NDPGM89152).

Comment: @wchiquito Your answer did it.  Thank you!  If you want to post it as an answer, I will happily accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `AND COUNT(priority) = 0` (`COUNT` with field name doesn't count null values), like this:

```
SELECT EID FROM tasks 
GROUP BY EID HAVING 
  COUNT(priority) = 0 AND
  COUNT(DISTINCT completed_form) = 1 AND MAX(completed_form) = 'y' AND
  COUNT(DISTINCT all_forms_in) = 1 AND MAX(all_forms_in) = 'y'AND
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: That creates Invalid use of group function